# Highlighting current url not working with request resolver

Tags: django

I have the following urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('landing', views.landing, name='landing'),
    path('json', views.json, name='json'),
    path('bootstrap', views.bootstrap, name='bootstrap'),
    path('page', views.page, name='page'),
]
```

I am using twitter bootstrap 5 and i want to highlight home when a user visits the landing page and append active when the current url matches

```
<li class="nav-item">
           <a href="{% url '' %}" class="nav-link {% if request.resolver_match.view_name == '' %}active{% endif %}">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{% url 'page' %}" class="nav-link {% if request.resolver_match.view_name == 'page' %}active{% endif %}">Page</a>
          </li>
```

I get this error

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Even when i replace the blank '' with 'landing' the active class is not appended.How can i correct this?

Comment: You need to replace both `''` in `{% url %}` tag and `{% if %}` tag with `'index'`

Comment: I made the code even shorter `<a href="{% url 'page' %}" class="nav-link {% if request.path == 'page' %}active{% endif %}">Page</a>` and this doesn't work as well.

Comment: Did you request the Home(index) url, or the page url? This should work when you visit "page". If not, check the url in your browser. Sometimes Django automatically add `/` to the end of url, and you would have to do the same in your `{% if %}` tag.

Comment: I am using this package and even this dont work https://pypi.org/project/django-active-link/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it this way

In my view

```
def pagex(request):
    return render(request, 'desktop/page.html', {'current': 'pagex'})
```

and in my template

```
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="{% url 'pagex' %}" class="nav-link {% if current == 'pagex' %}active{% endif %}">Page</a>
</li>
```